# How to fix rendering SLS failed: Jinja syntax error: expected token ',', got ':'?

Tags: python, django-templates, jinja2, salt-stack, icinga

I have a particular error on this line:

```
 {% set icinga_ticket = salt['http.query'](https://ticket-generator.az.dev.com method=POST header_dict='{"Content-Type":"application/json"}' data="'{\"hostname\": \"minion.node.jio.com\"}'" backend=requests) %}
```

I got:

```
rendering SLS 'base:icinga.icinga2_core' failed: Jinja syntax error: expected token ',', got ':'
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the options with `,` and quote non variables like this: `method='POST'`.

```
 {% set icinga_ticket = salt['http.query']('https://ticket-generator.az.dev.com', method='POST', header_dict='{"Content-Type":"application/json"}', data="'{\"hostname\": \"minion.node.jio.com\"}'", backend='requests') %}
```

Btw have a look at the icinga2 module: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.icinga2.html#salt.modules.icinga2.generate_ticket